# HTML file won't open

Tags: html

I am trying to open this html file but it wont. I wrote this code on my notepad, saved it with a .html extension. But when I try to open the html doc, the browser opens and the homepage is displayed. I did not find any mistake with the code though, anyways it is given below.

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<body>

<h1><strong> Preferable Links </strong></h1>

<a href="www.youtube.com"> Youtube </a> <br> <a href="www.google.com"> Google</a> <br> <a href="www.hotmail.com"> Hotmail </a> <br>

<h1> <i> END <i> </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: drag the file in the browser also your doctype is incorrect, should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: the coding doesnt matter, it should open anyway and simply be messed up if its wrong, but should still open. maybe you have some settings/extension in your browser that makes it open the home page on startup? also, maybe you have malware that changed your homepage to something like sweetsearch.com, and makes it open every time you start your browser?

Comment: Your links need to include the protocol (`http://www.youtube.com/` instead of `www.youtube.com`). The way it's written now, those would be considered relative links, and clicking on them would attempt to take you to a page named `www.youtube.com` living on your current server.

Comment: Are you using the Notepad++ code editor?

Comment: No, I am using the notePad which we find right clicking the screen. :D and thanks with the doctype thingy and the website link :D

Comment: @JoeEnos if i dont write http:// it wont connect with the main web server. Is that what you are trying to say man?

Comment: It's not your main problem but you'll see it when you try to click one of the links.

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes the link won't open. But what I said before, was it wrong?

Comment: The way you phrased it isn't quite right, but I think you see the issue. Clicking on a link just tells the browser "make a GET request to the address indicated". If you give it an absolute URL with protocol, like `http://example.com/` then it knows exactly where that GET goes. If you give it anything else, then when the link is clicked, it will try to create an absolute URL by combining the current page's address with what's in the `href` attribute, depending on what the `href` value looks like (or if you give it a hash on the current page, it doesn't make a new request at all).